# Swing beans binding: how do I notify the target that the model has changed?

Tags: swing, binding

I have a swing app with a text box bound to a property on my model (this is a READ_WRITE AutoBinding). The model also has an isDirty property that I want to bind to a button's enabled property.

How do I properly notify the binding when I change the state of isDirty.

Here is my binding code:

```
BeanProperty<PaChannelConfig, Boolean> paChannelConfigBeanProperty_1 = 
                      BeanProperty.create("dirty");
BeanProperty<JButton, Boolean> jButtonBeanProperty = 
                      BeanProperty.create("enabled");
AutoBinding<PaChannelConfig, Boolean, JButton, Boolean> autoBinding_2 = 
                      Bindings.createAutoBinding(
                                       UpdateStrategy.READ, 
                                       model, 
                                       paChannelConfigBeanProperty_1, 
                                       btnApply, jButtonBeanProperty);
autoBinding_2.bind();
```

What is the proper way to add this notification?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the model should have the methods

```
addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)
removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)
firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent)
```

look at the class PropertyChangeSupport, that class have implementations of the methods above.

In the model, the method `setDirty(boolean)` should be implemented like this:

```
public void setDirty(boolean dirty) {
    boolean old = this.dirty;
    this.dirty = dirty;
    firePropertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent("dirty", old, dirty));
}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) to easily implement support for property change notification. The documentation at the provided link has an example of how to set it up and use it.